# Correlation of location to specific numerical values

Tags: correlation, coordinate-descent, location-parameter

I'm trying to calculate the correlation of specific locations (I have latitude and longitude data)
to specific numerical values I have. Does anyone know any particular methods to do this? I have calculated correlations
before but not involving point data or latitude and longitude data.